# How can i limit the number of nested entities in API Platform?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, api-platform.com

Having two related entities, let's say Author and Book, I can limit (or paginate) the results of Authors but not the number of results of its related entity Books which always shows the whole collection.

The issue is that Authors may have hundreds of Books making the resulting JSON huge and heavy to parse so I'm trying to get, for example, only the last 5 books.

I'm sure I'm missing something since I think this is probably a common scenario but I can't find anything on the docs nor here in StackOverflow.

I'm starting with Api Platform, any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it creating a normalizer for the entity but I still think that it has to be a simpler solution.

Here's what I had to do, following the Authors / Books example:

Add a setter to the Author entity to override the Author's Book collection:

```php
// src/Entity/Author.php

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
// ...

/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AuthorRepository")
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Book", mappedBy="author", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $books;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Getters and setters
    //...

    public function setBooks($books): self
    {
        $this->books = $books;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Create a normalizer for the Author's entity:

```php
// App/Serializer/Normalizer/AuthorNormalizer.php

<?php

namespace App\Serializer\Normalizer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Api\IriConverterInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\AbstractItemNormalizer;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareTrait;

class AuthorNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
{
    use SerializerAwareTrait;

    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(
        NormalizerInterface $normalizer,
        IriConverterInterface $iriConverter
    ) {
        if (!$normalizer instanceof DenormalizerInterface) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The normalizer must implement the DenormalizerInterface');
        }
        if (!$normalizer instanceof AbstractItemNormalizer) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The normalizer must be an instance of AbstractItemNormalizer');
        }
        $handler = function ($entity) use ($iriConverter) {
            return $iriConverter->getIriFromItem($entity);
        };
        $normalizer->setMaxDepthHandler($handler);
        $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler($handler);
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->normalizer->denormalize($data, $class, $format, $context);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->normalizer->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format);
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        // Number of desired Books to list
        $limit = 2;
        $newBooksCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        $books = $object->getBooks();
        $booksCount = count($books);
        if ($booksCount > $limit) {

            // Reverse iterate the original Book collection as I just want the last ones
            for ($i = $booksCount; $i > $booksCount - $limit; $i--) {
                $newBooksCollection->add($books->get($i - 1));
            }
        }

        // Setter previously added to the Author entity to override its related Books
        $object->setBooks($newBooksCollection);
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof \App\Entity\Author;
    }
}
```

And finally register the normalizer as a service manually (using autowire led me to circular reference issues):

```
services:
    App\Serializer\Normalizer\AuthorNormalizer:
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: true
        arguments:
            $normalizer: '@api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'
            $iriConverter: '@ApiPlatform\Core\Api\IriConverterInterface'
```

Comment: May be you should look at [Pagination - API Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/), hard coding is not an answer, how are you going to fetch rest of books or related authors?

Comment: You are totally right. I've posted this answer because a piece of code like this would have been helpful when I wrote the question but definitely it's only a place to start.

Comment: I just discovered Api Platform some weeks ago and really think that it's very powerful and customizable but IMO things starts going hard when working on relationships / subresources. Also think is more about a lack of documentation in this matter than the platform itself being restrictive on the subresources results customisation. Why can't I just copy-paste everything from the docs? :P

Comment: You are quite right, I have been working on a complex project since couple of weeks, to make things clear [Extending API Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extending/) <--- This page is the most Important to getting started. At the end I opted for DTO, MessageHandlers with Both Normalizer / Denormalizer rather than using custom operations. It adds complexity of attaching like 6 Logical class to an resource but at the end of the day it will help alot in separating logic. To be honest, learning curve is so steep here, but when you start understanding it's internals, it gets easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experience.